# Installation using Jekyll fails on OS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: jekyll, ffi

I have an issue installing Jekyll, because ffi is not working:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190721-87601-s2b792.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
checking for ruby_thread_has_gvl_p()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
Configuring libffi
configure: error: in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-darwin18':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-darwin18"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0/ffi-1.11.1/gem_make.out
```

It seems like ffi-1.11.1 is not working with jekyll. Has anyone been successful in installing jekyll? I'm using OS Mojave version 10.14.5.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this [issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/651) in the ffi repo and also [this issue](https://github.com/github/personal-website/issues/7) on Github which might be helpful, even if the error is slightly different this might be a trace to start for you.

Also, the solution and explanation provided [in this issue](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/653) looks very promising:

> Finally I realised that I had a version of Xcode that was not updated because High Sierra is too older to support the lastest version (Thank you Apple...).
>   So I tried to enter the command gcc -v and I saw this line :
>
> Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38).
>
> That was the problem ! Even If I installed the latest Xcode Command Line Developer Tools, the old gcc provided with Xcode was still used.
>   I entered the command xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ and the command gcc -v displayed the new version :
>
> Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)

High Sierra and Mojave might have the same issue with outdated xcode stuff here.